# Android WebView не работает корректно

Tags: android, webview

С сервера приходит ссылка на эквайринг сбербанка, при открытии заполняю форму но оплата не проходит.

```
webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
```

В чем может быть проблема?
Если заполнять через браузер компьютера, то все проходит успешно

Answer (score 0, accepted):

удалось решить проблему добавив эти настройки

```
webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
    webView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
    webView.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);
    webView.getSettings().setAllowContentAccess(true);
    webView.getSettings().setAllowFileAccessFromFileURLs(true);
    webView.getSettings().setAllowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs(true);
    webView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
```

Comment: не работает на всех устройствах, в чем может быть проблема?